# How to permanent redirect old domain to new one. in case amazon store

Tags: redirect, htaccess

How do I permanently redirect this url using .htaccess, so that if anyone views old web page, it redirects to the new one.

For example:

```
http://olddomain.com/folder/AmazonASIN.html  
--> http://newdomain.com/AmazonASIN.html

http://oldexample.com/detail/B007OZNZG0.html   
--> http://newexample.com/B007OZNZG0.html
```

Comment: Is your site located on your own server, a webhotel or what?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 http://oldexample.com/detail/B007OZNZG0.html http://newexample.com/B007OZNZG0.html
```

#### UPDATE

Ok, maybe my answer was a bit short but if you only want to redirect a couple of URL's that code will work great. The thing is, if there's no real logic between your old and your new URL's I think you should do a bit of reading before you start adding redirects, it's not that hard really. See this code for example (taken from [this site](http://www.squidoo.com/301)):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.new-site.com
Redirect 301 /old-category/old-page-1 http://www.new-site.com/new-page
Redirect 301 /old-category/old-page-2 http://www.new-site.com/new-page
Redirect 301 /old-category/old-page-3 http://www.new-site.com/new-page
Redirect 301 /old-category/old-page-4 http://www.new-site.com/new-page
Redirect 301 /old-category/old-page-5 http://www.new-site.com/new-page
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old-category-2/(.*)$ http://www.new-site.com/widgets/blue
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old-category-3/(.*)$ http://www.new-site.com/widgets/blue
```

The third line is redirecting your home page, the next five lines are redirecting specific URL's from old ones to new ones and the last two – RedirectMatch 301 – redirects all URL's starting with old-category-2 and old-category-3. Also, you can test your redirects by typing 302 instead of 301, 302 is not as permanent as 301.

I hope that will get you started at least!

Comment: @Richard thanks for your recommendation. I know understood.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i don't have the code. :)

Comment: @AlexG.Bale : What code did I ask you for?